# Remove AppPreview on iTunes for specific language

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, app-preview

I have in my application a video as an App Preview of my application. I have my game localized with up to 10 languages.

The thing is, I don't want to show this AppPreview in French and Italian, but I can't find any way to filter this, looks like it is shared for all languages.

Do you know if it's possible?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to have different "versions" of your App Preview, i.e. you cannot even delete it for specific languages. What Linus is referring to only concerns screenshots.

> An app preview demonstrates the features, functionality, and user
>   interface of your app or game in a short video that users can watch
>   right on the App Store. Each preview is between 15 and 30 seconds long
>   and appears in **all countries or regions where your app is available**.
>   For details on capturing app footage, see Creating Videos for App
>   Previews.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-previews/

In-depth properties: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW10